# true/false issue in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using `ENUM ('true','false')` in database for testMode. If the testMode is `true` it is working fine but when I switch it false it is stay `true` not switch `false`. What I did wrong or what is my mistake anyone can tell me please ?

```
'stripe'    => [
   'enable'   => $Status ? true : false,
   'testMode' => $Mode ? true : false, //test mode or live mode (boolean, true or false)  
 ],
```

Comment: Your enums are strings, so use strings. Why one is bool and another string `'false'`

Comment: @ChrisHaas What should I do?

Comment: @Justinas Why one is bool and another string 'false' => Sorry this is my mistake, edited.

Comment: @Azzo So again, your enums are strings, but you pass booleans. Why not use `TINYINT(1)` for boolean? If still need strings, pass it as strings `$status ? 'true' : 'false'`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html#enum-limits

Comment: @Justinas Thanks for your friendly answer it will help me much. And I gave you more votes in your other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your enum consists of two strings `'true'` and `'false'`.

But in code you pass booleans `true` and `false` that later on includes conversion magic.

So you should store it as strings too:

```
'stripe'    => [
   'enable'   => $Status ? 'true' : 'false',
   'testMode' => $Mode ? 'true' : 'false', //test mode or live mode (boolean, true or false)  
 ],
```

---

I do not suggest using Enum for such true/false values as you will have issues later on. Most common practice is to use it as `TINYINT(1)` and passing boolean `true`/`false` values - it will save database space and will not bring type conversion errors when you try to do `$row['testMode'] == true`